# Brownian sheet as a martingale measure.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}_t, P)$ be a stochastic basis. Define a one-dimensional two-parameter and $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted centered Gaussian process $W(x,t)$ with

$$E[W(x,t)W(y,s)]=\min(x,y)\min(s,t).$$

Is it possible to prove $W(x,t)$ as a martingale measure as defined following way viva J.B. Walsh (Chapter 2, page 287)

> **Definition.** Let $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ be a right continuous filtration. A process $\{M_t(A), \mathcal{F}_t, t>0\}$ is a martingale measure if
>
> - (i) $M_0(A)=0;$
> - (ii) if $t>0$, $M_t$ is a $\sigma$-finite $L^{2}$-valued measure;
> - (iii) $\{M_t(A), \mathcal{F}_t, t>0\}$ is a martingale.

$\rangle\rangle$ My question is can we prove that $W(x,t)$ is a martingale measure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Martingale Measures are Gaussian processes indexed by time and measurable subsets of e.g. $\mathbb{R}^d$. The Brownian sheet is indexed by time and points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. How do you intend to define a viable candidate for a martingale measure from the Brownian sheet?